# how to use ngIf* to validate if a variable is null? angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm using this code to consume a service data and save it information in an array.

```
activities: [];

this.activitiesService.getUserActivities().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.activities = data;
    });
```

The trouble is when I use *ngIf to show or hide a ng-container if activities[0] is null, appear this error:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
[image]

I show you my code:

```
           <ng-container *ngIf="activities[0]">
              <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 actividad">
                <div class="testmonial_author text-center activity-active">
                  <i class="fas {{ activities[0].category }}"></i>
                  <span>{{ activities[0].description }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!activities[0]">
              <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 actividad">
                <div class="testmonial_author text-center" (click)="openModalActivity()">
                  <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                  <span>Crea una actividad</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
```

I tried whit this code but is not working.

```
           <ng-container *ngIf="activities[0]; else activity">
              <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 actividad">
                <div class="testmonial_author text-center activity-active">
                  <i class="fas {{ activities[0].category }}"></i>
                  <span>{{ activities[0].description }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #activity>
              <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 actividad">
                <div class="testmonial_author text-center" (click)="openModalActivity()">
                  <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                  <span>Crea una actividad</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `activities` is undefined. If the `activities` is not undefined check the index[0].

```
<ng-container *ngIf="activities && activities[0]; else activity">
```